# Homogenous ODE, How do I demonstrate a proof using a function from the ODE itself

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification, wronskian

[image]

I have attempted this problem multiple times. I found the Wronskian and it's derivative. I am solely confused by how to use $~p(t)~$ in the proof itself. I attempted to say that $~Ay_1 + By_2~$ is also a solution. I then plugged in both the first and second derivative into the ODE and solved for $~P(t)~$ and then multiplied that by the Wronskian.

Is my approach and understanding of this problem wrong, if so, what am I misinterpreting?

Comment: This is called Abel's identity (spoiler: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_identity) All you need to know is $y''_i = -py'_i - qy_i$ and substitute in the expression for $W'$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $~y_1(t)~$ and $~y_2(t)~$ are solutions of the differential equation $$y''+p(t)y'+q(t)y=0\tag1$$ so, they also satisfy the equation $(1)$ i.e., 
$$y_1''+p(t)y_1'+q(t)y_1=0\tag2$$
$$y_2''+p(t)y_2'+q(t)y_2=0\tag3$$
Multiply $~y_2~$ in equation $(2)$, $~y_1~$ in equation $(3)$ and then subtracting we have
$$(y_2y_1''-y_1y_2'')+p(t)(y_2y_1'-y_1y_2')+q(t)(y_1y_2-y_2y_1)=0$$
$$\implies(y_2y_1''-y_1y_2'')+p(t)(y_2y_1'-y_1y_2')=0$$
$$\implies -\frac{d}{dt}W(y_1,y_2)(t)-p(t)W(y_1,y_2)(t)=0$$ 
$$\implies W'(y_1,y_2)(t)=-p(t)~W(y_1,y_2)(t)$$

---

**Note:**

Wronskian $$W(y_1,y_2)(t)=\begin{vmatrix} 
y_1 & y_2 \\
y_1' & y_2' 
\end{vmatrix}=y_1y_2'-y_2y_1'$$
Also $$\frac{d}{dt}W(y_1,y_2)(t)=y_1y_2''+y_1'y_2'-y_2y_1''-y_2'y_1'=y_1y_2''-y_2y_1''$$